# Pass a random number to a program in a script

Tags: bash, random, while-loop

I have a very simple question. I have a program that accepts an integer number as input (followed by a CR). I want to run this program a number of times, and I want this integer number to be a different (random) number each time. So I want to wrap everything in a shell script, but I don't really know how to implement it. I am thinking something along the lines of the following code, but the 12345 replaced by $RANDOM. How should I do it? 
Thanks a bunch in advance,
S.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i -le 100 ]
do
./recomb100runs << !!
12345
!!
done
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$RANDOM`...? ;)

Comment: From what I know, everything that is between !! !! is passed to the program "as it is". So if I substitute 12345 with $RANDOM, my program will literally get $RANDOM, not the random number. So I would get an error. Am I right?

Comment: Variable expansion is still performed for heredoc strings.  You can test it out with `cat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `$((RANDOM))`:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while [ $i -le 100 ]
do
cat << !!
$((RANDOM))
!!
done
```

(Replace "cat" with the script you want to run with the random input -- in your case "`./recomb100runs`".)

Comment: You don't need to use the arithmetic context: `$RANDOM` works perfectly well. It's a bit more elegant to use a here-string instead of a here-doc in this case: `cat <<< $RANDOM`